# Array as query string

Tags: javascript

I've created a function that pushes objects into an array onclick. How do I use that array as a query string combined with other query string parameters?

```
<input type="checkbox" onclick="querySearch('uno')" id="coverage1">
    <input type="checkbox" onclick="querySearch('dos')" id="coverage2">
    <input type="checkbox" onclick="querySearch('tres')" id="coverage3">
    <input type="checkbox" onclick="querySearch('quattro')" id="coverage4">
    <script>
        let searchCoverage = [];

        function querySearch(a) {
            if (searchCoverage.indexOf(a) > -1) {
                searchCoverage.splice(searchCoverage.indexOf(a), 1);
            }
            else {
            searchCoverage.push(a);
        }
            if (searchCoverage.length == 0) {
                console.log();
            }
            else {
                console.log(searchCoverage);
            }
        }
```

This outputs an array in the console as long as there are objects in the array. I would like to add this array to a href but my problem is there are multiple query string parameters already in that href.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A typical query has not a list of entries but a list of key-value pairs. You can generate a query from a JSON with

```new URLSearchParams (my_json).toString()```. If you want to create a query from a list you have to specify how the query should look like.

Comment: This [MDN doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/URLSearchParams) might help. It shows how to add new query paramters to an existing url. See the second block below the text "This example shows how to build a new URL with an object of search parameters from an existing URL that has search parameters."